Get SerialName param from child class in Kotlin kotlinx serialization
I have a parent class RequestFieldResponseBody and two classes that inherit from it (CreateRequestFieldBody and EditRequestFieldBody). I would like to make it so that depending on the child class my id is converted to SerialName("request_field") and @SerialName("issue_field") respectively
@Serializable
internal open class RequestFieldResponseBody(
    open val id: Int,
    @Serializable(with = ValueSerializer::class)
    val value: Value
) {
    @Serializable
    sealed class Value {
        
        // ...
    }
}

@Serializable
internal data class CreateRequestFieldBody(
    @SerialName("request_field")
    override val id: Int,
    val createValue: Value
) : RequestFieldResponseBody(id, createValue)

@Serializable
internal data class EditRequestFieldBody(
    @SerialName("issue_field")
    override val id: Int,
    val editValue: Value
) : RequestFieldResponseBody(id, editValue)

Now when I make a request, this is what I get:
{
  "id": 281,
  "value": [
    5016
  ]
}

Here's what I want to get:
{
   "request_field": 281,
   "value": [
      5016
   ]
}

and
{
   "issue_field": 281,
   "value": [
      5016
   ]
}


I think you have three choices here as the @SerialName annotation does not work exactly how you would like: (i) make the base class and its fields abstract (which may not be possible), (ii) have the subclasses inherit functionality from the base class by composition (and maybe a shared interface) rather than inheritance, or (iii) write the serializers for these classes by hand, which I think could be done in one class.
